# ionic white screen after splashscreen

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, wifi

I wrote a script to detect if there is a wifi connection or not. However, I noticed, that if the app starts when there is no wifi connection, the splashscreen will load and then i'll get a white screen. The console shows this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

this is my script for detecting the wifi and its placed in the '$ionicPlatform.ready':

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState)
    {
      connectionerror($ionicPopup)
    })

    //display error msg and close the app.
    function connectionerror($ionicPopup,$scope)
    {
      var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({ 
        title: 'Network Error',
        content: 'No internet connectivity detected. Please try again.',
        buttons: [
        {
          text: '<b>Retry</b>',
          type: 'button-positive',
          onTap: function(e) 
          {
            if (!$cordovaNetwork.isOnline()) 
            {
              e.preventDefault();  
            }
            else 
            {
              $state.reload();
            }
          }
        }]
      });
    }
```

How do I fix it so that after the splashscreen, if there is no wifi, the message would show ?

Answer (score 0):

The error happens when you are trying to load a resource from your pc probably. If you are running ionic serve or ionic serve live and you disconnect the wifi, the app will try to load a template form your pc using wifi and won't be able to do it.

To test that script you should build the app and run it on a device.

If that's working, the controller should be working differently. It should look more like this:

```
.controller('controller', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicPopup, $cordovaNetwork){
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState)
      {
        connectionerror()
      })

    //display error msg and close the app.
    function connectionerror()
    {
      var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({ 
        title: 'Network Error',
        content: 'No internet connectivity detected. Please try again.',
        buttons: [
        {
          text: '<b>Retry</b>',
          type: 'button-positive',
          onTap: function(e) 
          {
            if (!$cordovaNetwork.isOnline()) 
            {
              e.preventDefault();  
            }
            else 
            {
              //go to a state like index or home instead of reload. Reload resets the application and should be avioded in single page apps
              $state.go('...'); 
            }
          }
        }]
      });
    } 
})
```

Comment: Actually I am running the app from the device. And the device is not connected to the pc at the time of the test. When I switch off my wifi then start the app, the splash screen loads then I get the white screen with the error I mentioned in the question

Comment: can you post the whole controller?